# MariaDB 10.4.6 drop field level CHECK constraint problem

Tags: mariadb, constraints, check-constraints

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    height int(10) CHECK(height>5)
);
```

When I try to remove `check constraint` by:

```
ALTER TABLE test DROP CONSTRAINT height;
```

I got this error message:

```
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP CONSTRAINT `height`; check that it exists
```

Here is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE test;` command output:

```
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                      
|
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
`height` int(10) DEFAULT NULL CHECK (`height` > 5)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And here is the `SELECT * from information_schema.table_constraints where TABLE_NAME = 'test';` output:

```
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----------------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA     | TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----------------+
| def                | test_db           | height          | test_db          | test       | CHECK           |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: MySQL has [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) that: "*The optional symbol specifies a name for the constraint. If omitted, MySQL generates a name from the table name, a literal _chk_, and an ordinal number (1, 2, 3, ...)*" ; however Mariadb [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-table/) is not explicit about the name of the constraint. My recommendation is to use `CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> CHECK ...` syntax to avoid such issues. Check fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=7e6e6ac15f3d052480f9504bd11986d6

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Thanks for the comment, but I cannot change the constraint creation behavior. it is created automatically by the framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [CREATE TABLE :: Constraint
>   Expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#constraint-expressions)
>
> ...
>
> MariaDB 10.2.1 introduced two ways to define a constraint:
>
> - CHECK(expression) given as part of a column definition.
> - CONSTRAINT [constraint_name] CHECK (expression)
>
> ...

If you define the constraint using the first form (column constraint), you can remove it using `MODIFY COLUMN`:

```js
ALTER TABLE `test`
  MODIFY COLUMN `height` INT(10);
```

If you use the second form (table constraint), you can remove it using `DROP CONSTRAINT`:

```js
ALTER TABLE `test`
  DROP CONSTRAINT `height`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3f5e20272df94a0ba9d7fa10b4505124).